# Movimientos exactos con Delta-Time. En SDL con C++

Tags: c++, algoritmos, optimización

Estoy creando un juego *2D* con *C++* y *SDL*, donde en la gestión del tiempo uso la técnica *Delta-Time* (tiempo delta) para movimientos con desplazamientos suaves. La ejecución es perfecta, sin embargo hay desplazamientos de objetos (plataformas) que dependen del tiempo, es decir, que para moverse, por ejemplo, *500px* debe hacerlo en 6 segundos, todo bien hasta este punto.

Nota: El movimiento es perpetuo, es decir se repite infinitamente

El problema se produce cuando hay más objetos, puesto que si hay dos o más objetos con la misma duración y diferentes velocidades, se observa un desfase de retardo entre los objetos, ya que **deberían llegar a su destino en el mismo tiempo**. Es comprensible porque *Delta-Time* no tiene el mismo retardo entre cada **fotograma** y genera desplazamiento por pixeles variados.

¿Hay alguna forma de controlar el desfase, o existe otro método para este tipo de movimiento que dependen de un tiempo específico?

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje estás creando el juego? ¿En C o en C++? **¡¡El lenguaje C/C++ no existe!!**

Comment: Es c++ , lo siento es la costumbre.

Comment: Si el movimiento de ciertos elementos es uniforme, no necesitas delta: es una ecuación lineal: puedes predecir con exactitud la posición del elemento en T0 y TX.

Comment: Publicar un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema puede ayudar a que te proporcionemos respuestas más concretas.

Comment: Sean los objetos A con velocidad 100px / 6.5 seg y  B con 250px / 6.5 seg.   Los incrementos lógicos de A y B lo hacen con su deltaTime * velocidad respectiva. De forma que ese ciclo de movimiento termina por dar un valor en 100.0113 px en A y 249.0215 en B, que luego se transforman en enteros para el renderizado, esos decimales de exceso y defecto hacen que algunos movimientos se retrasen. Y no tengo idea como manipular el delta-time, o el control de movimientos :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estas buscando es realizar algo que se llama [Interpolación lineal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolaci%C3%B3n).

Tu objetivo cada vez que que llamas a la función donde pintas tu escena **no es pintar cada objeto** sino **calcular donde debe ser pintado cada objeto**, según el tiempo transcurrido.

Para ello, debes definir el valor de origen, el valor fin y el tiempo que tardará la variable objetivo en llegar al valor fin.

Aquí tienes [un vídeo en inglés](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJq7I2DLGzI) que te explica como realizar un movimiento suave de un personaje.

Como comentas que lo estas abordando en c++, busca librerías de interpolación como por ejemplo este [port de Tween](https://github.com/kleemedia/universal-tween-engine-cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Si es vital que se mantenga la sincronización de la posición de estos objetos, te recomiendo que en lugar de calcular la nueva posición de cada objeto en función de la posición actual, la calcules de forma absoluta en función del tiempo.

Es decir, ahora mismo tendrás algo como:

```
pos = pos + vel*deltaTime.
```

En lugar de eso, puedes poner algo como:

```
totaltime+= deltatime
pos = vel * totaltime`
```

Si en vez de un movimiento lineal, quieres un movimiento de ida y vuelta, lo mismo, utiliza totaltime para calcular cual sería la posición en un momento dado.

Comment: Podría ser una solución, entonces cuando **totalTime** sea superior **TiempoRequerido**, de existir alguna diferencia **totalTime - TiempoRequerido > 0** , se sumaria ese tiempo para el próximo movimiento. ¿Es así o enfoque mal :/ ?

Comment: Resuelto, efectivamente era un problema lineal como lo menciona David Isla, solo tenía que enfocarme en el tiempo y no la posición como lo dice la respuesta de este publicación. jejeje un fallo en la lógica de programación muchas gracias a todos.